# iOS Animate text like powerpoint

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-text

I am making an application to create presentations. I would like to animate the texts like one in powerpoint. I don't know where to start. I searched in Google but i did not find any samples.Please help me by giving any tutorial links. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with `CGAffineTransformMake` method and it's options. You will be able to make rotation, change size and move objects on the screen. There are a lot of animations in MS PP, but some of them can be easily created with such transformations.  Read here [CGAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to give a good answer. What specific types of animations are you looking to do? UIView animation methods like animateWithDuration:animation: and it's variants let you do a whole lot like slides, fades, zooms, pans, rotations, etc. If you want to do wipes, page flips, venetian blind animations, there are a number of built-in transition animations you can use, or you can roll up your sleeves and learn the intricacies of Core Animation. Expect to spend weeks or months learning the finer points of Core animations if you want to do complex transitions that aren't supported directly however (like wipes, Venetian blinds, barn doors, etc.)